# How to read email date, attachement info, message id, ... in Lightning component on Lightning for Outlook?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

As the messageBody is expoxed, see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155790

any idea how to get the email date and attachment info?

We have 2 requirements:

1- Save more info in the related custom object to the incoming email 2- Save the original .eml/.msg file in Salesforce document.

For both we neeed the date, email id in exchange/gmail, or so on...

We already know how to lookup in Exchange 365 for an email and extract its .msg/.eml, but we need more information available in the Lightning Outlook component in order to properly execute the search in the Exchange 365 inbox.

Or maybe there are another aproach to meet these goals, are there?

Comment: Have u ever figure out, reading Attachments info from email?